# Convert a sparse matrix to a full matrix - R

Tags: r

I am looking for an efficient way to convert a huge sparse matrix to a full matrix (not to a dataframe) in R?

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use `as.matrix`

```
m1 <- as.matrix(sM)
```

where `sM` is the sparse matrix.

We can check the `methods`

```
grep("as.matrix", methods(class = "sparseMatrix"), value = TRUE)
#[1] "as.matrix,Matrix-method"
```

Comment: Thanks @akuran. what is check the `methods` for?

Comment: @EsterSilva It is just to know whether there is a `as.matrix` for conversion to `matrix`