# matrix type in R conversion

Tags: r, matrix, type-conversion, double, numeric

I have a matrix that looks like this :
[image]

It seems that it is as I understand a numeric matrix .
(it contains only values of 0,1,and 2)
the sparse matrix is created with the package sim1000G :

```
get_genotype=function(vcf_path){
  vcf = readVCF( vcf_path ,min_maf = NA, max_maf = NA,maxNumberOfVariants = 10000)
  startSimulation(vcf, totalNumberOfIndividuals = 3010)
  ids = generateUnrelatedIndividuals(3000)
  genotype = retrieveGenotypes(ids)
  return(genotype)
  
}


genotype_HLA_DRB5=get_genotype("HLA_DRB5.vcf")
```

I have another matrix that looks like this [image]

```
dim(genotype_sorcs)
[1] 3000 3984
```

what I would like to do is convert the second matrix so it would  not be Large matrix but will look like the first one meaning : num[1:3000,1:3984]

I tried this :

```
genotype_sorcs=as.numeric(genotype_sorcs)
```

But it didn't produce the desired output .Would be happy for your help

Comment: `as.numeric(.)` is going to create a vector, not a matrix. It looks like `genotype_sorcs` is something other than a vector since it has `dim(.)`, so ... what does `class(genotype_sorcs)` return? Perhaps a sparse matrix? You might be able to do `newgeno <- as.matrix(genotype_sorcs)`.

Comment: @r2evans > class(genotype_sorcs)
[1] "matrix" "array"  and > class(genotype_HLA_DRB5)
[1] "matrix" "array"  they are both sparse   i tried as you suggested newgeno <- as.matrix(genotype_sorcs) but stil its large matrix and not num[ 1:3000,1:3984] as the first matrix

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37764428/3358272 suggests that `as.matrix(.)` should be all you need, how were the sparse matrices created? With what package?

Comment: @r2evans hi , i tried it it still in the global environment as large matrix and not num [1:3000,,1:3984]

Comment: I think you are calling your matrices "sparse" meaning a property of the data. This is confusing because what you have are dense matrix objects and not sparse matrix objects in R. You should probably use sparse matrix data structures (see the [Matrix package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Matrix)).

Answer (score 0):

```
mode(genotype_sorcs)="numeric"
```

transforms it

Comment: If you have data that are expected to be numeric but are not numeric, you should investigate why that is the case. Just coercing the data to numeric and assuming everything is fine is quite risky.